# ML.net in Web API

Tags: c#, web-services, ml.net

I was trying to use ML.net since a Web API, I followed all the steps of the tutorial of ML.net in https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/machine-learning/tutorials/taxi-fare

But, when I try to use the service I have the message :  **"Transforms.CategoricalHashOneHotVectorizer" not found**
int the line

```
model = pipeline.Train<Trazability, TrazabilityPrediction>();
```

I don't know how can obtain a correct response in the tutorial but when I tried to put the same code  in a Web Api proyect obtain this wrong.

Here the code that I did:

Class Program.cs

```
public class Program
{
    const string _datapath = @".\Datos\Train.csv";
    const string _testdatapath = @".\Datos\Test.csv";
    const string _modelpath = @".\Datos\Model.zip";

    public float predicion()
    {
        var prediccion = DuracionDias();
        return float.Parse(prediccion.ToString());
    }

    public async Task<TrazabilityPrediction> DuracionDias() {

        PredictionModel<Trazability, TrazabilityPrediction> model = await Train();
        Evaluate(model);
        TrazabilityPrediction prediction = model.Predict(TrazabilityTest.Prueba1);

        return prediction;
    }

    public static async Task<PredictionModel<Trazability, TrazabilityPrediction>> Train()
    {
        PredictionModel<Trazability, TrazabilityPrediction> model = null;

        try
        {

            var pipeline = new LearningPipeline();
            pipeline.Add(new TextLoader(_datapath).CreateFrom<Trazability>(useHeader: true, separator: ';'));
            pipeline.Add(new ColumnCopier(("duracionDias", "Label")));
            pipeline.Add(new CategoricalHashOneHotVectorizer("producto", "proveedor"));
            pipeline.Add(new ColumnConcatenator("Features", "producto", "proveedor", "peso"));
            pipeline.Add(new FastTreeRegressor());

            model = pipeline.Train<Trazability, TrazabilityPrediction>();
            await model.WriteAsync(path: _modelpath);

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception(e.Message);
        }

        return model;
    }

    private static void Evaluate(PredictionModel<Trazability, TrazabilityPrediction> model)
    {
        var testData = new TextLoader(_testdatapath).CreateFrom<Trazability>(useHeader: true, separator: ';');

        var evaluator = new RegressionEvaluator();

        RegressionMetrics metrics = evaluator.Evaluate(model, testData);

        Console.WriteLine($"Rms = {metrics.Rms}");
        Console.WriteLine($"RSquared = {metrics.RSquared}");

    }


}
```

and here are the models

```
 public class Trazability
{
    [Column("0")]
    public string producto;

    [Column("1")]
    public string proveedor;

    [Column("2")]
    public float peso;

    [Column("3")]
    public float duracionDias;
}

public class TrazabilityPrediction
{
    [ColumnName("Score")]
    public float duracionDias;
}
```

Also here have the .csv (train.csv and test.csv)

```
producto;proveedor;peso;duracionDias
Azucar;Sol;10;12
Azucar;Sol;10;12
Azucar;Sol;10;12
Azucar;Sol;10;12
Azucar;Sol;10;12
Azucar;Sol;20;24
Azucar;Sol;20;24
Azucar;Sol;20;24
Azucar;Sol;20;24
Azucar;Sol;20;24
Colorante;Sol;10;12
Colorante;Sol;10;12
Colorante;Sol;10;12
Colorante;Sol;10;12
Colorante;Sol;10;12
Colorante;Sol;20;24
Colorante;Sol;20;24
Colorante;Sol;20;24
Colorante;Sol;20;24
Colorante;Sol;20;24
```

please help me

Comment: Is there any additional information in the error you can share? It is strange that `ColumnCopier` works but `CategoricalHashOneHotVectorizer` does not, given that they are in the same assembly. Were you able to run the same pipeline in a console app and get results?

Comment: Yest @GalOshri when I run the same pipeline in a console app it works. I don't  know what to do

Comment: Historically it's been caused by the fact that the necessary DLLs were not copied into the bin folder of the webside.

Comment: Actually, if you upgrade to 0.6 you might have this problem resolve itself, since we changed the way dependency injection works in that version

Answer (score 1):

I have created a POC using the code and sample data you have provided.I am able to get the following output when I run the application.Please note I am using the ML.NET version 5.0

[image]

I think that your application is good but it is different version of ML.NET which is the problem.There have been couple of changes in the recent version.

If you need to use the features in the previous versions you can use the Microsoft.ML.Legacy namespace.